# GC in Java 8 get obviously slower compare to Java 7

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have a server with 72 GB memory running, it was use Java 7 with parallel GC and heap size in 25G. But after switch into Java 8, a particular task get much slower. The task basically read a file around 15GB in the memory, and update some relevant data in DB. It usually takes around one hour to finished the job, but after Java 8, it becomes 1.5 hours.

I tried:

1. Increase heap size to 50GB => not help
2. Change GC algorithm from parallel to CMS, it becomes even slower (1.8 hour)

So I am not sure where I can start to have a look, the java library to run the task is still compiled in Java 7 but I am not sure if this relevant?
After switch to Java 7, the performance just came back.

Comment: Have you run a profiler against your application? What third party libraries are you using to load this file?

Comment: The latest Java 7? The implementation if substrings changed! Try comparing benchmarks between the two to see where the performance went.

Comment: Anything taking that long would benefit from profiling. (Any thing taking longer than a minute should be profiled IMHO)

Comment: @AndreM Hi, the lib is just some java code I wrote, it basically read data from hdfs
.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, yes I think I should, problem the server is running in production, guess I need somehow to test that without having influence the system's performance

Comment: @Chia-ChuanWu You could take a flight recording which has << 5% impact.

Comment: Maybe you're simply affected by changing defaults. Append `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to your 7 and 8 JVM args and see what changed.

Comment: would it be possible to share the code via GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare/find GC issue, it's better to enable GC logging:

- -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:logs/gc.log

and use GCViewer to parse/visualize GC log files. It will be useful if you gather GC log and attach it to question.

In theory (and practice), Java 8 is faster than Java 7. You mentioned that Java writes data to DB. It may be worth to analyze resource consumption of both, may be DB is root cause.

Comment: Hi,  I would take a look of this thanks for these flags!